# Force Rails Paypal gem to use Sandbox instead of Live

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

**A short story**: I installed a development server on Heroku that is running in production mode.

I am not very familiar to the `paypal-sdk-rest` gem that is installed in this app (actually I'm new to RoR).

Reading the documentation here https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK I found out that there is a config yml file (`config/paypal.yml`)  with the client_id and the client_secret for both Sandbox and Live for development and production environments. And a reference it to in `config/initializers/paypal.rb`.

When I'm working on localhost I can create payments on Sandbox and when I'm on my AWS server I can create payments on Live. But on Heroku I need it to create payments on Sandbox and not on Live. So I commented the reference to `paypal.yml` in `paypal.rb` and stated this in paypal.rb:

```
#this was added 
PayPal::SDK.configure({
   :mode => "sandbox",
   :client_id => "my-sandbox-id",
   :client_secret => "my-sandbox-secret"
})
```

Before sending files to Heroku I'm testing on localhost and I was expecting to see the sandbox payment page since it was working before removing the configuration file. I'm getting this message error instead:

> {"name"=>"BUSINESS_VALIDATION_ERROR",
>   "details"=>[{"field"=>"validation_error", "issue"=>"Incorrect Template
>   Id."}], "message"=>"Validation Error.",
>   "information_link"=>"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#BUSINESS_VALIDATION_ERROR",
>   "debug_id"=>"some id here"}

**Additional information**: before removing the configuration file I was just copying the development info to production. I was testing on Heroku and getting the same error.

Any ideas folks?

Answer (score 0):

I would add the keys via an environment variable.  That way each environment will reference the correct key and you don't have to check them into source control.  https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro is a good gem if you want to go that route.  Alternatively you can set up your config/paypal.yml file to reference the different environments.  That would look more like:

```
development:
  :mode: "sandbox"
  :client_id: "my-sandbox-id"

production:
  :mode: "not-sandbox-er-whatever"
  :client_id: "my-not-sandbox-id"
```

Comment: yes. that's what I originally got. But I tried on Heroku to make both work on sandbox. And then I get that error

Comment: I am guessing that the configuration file is being used for more than just being referenced by paypal.rb but I could be wrong.  In any case using environment variables should solve this issue.  You can test it by having the paypal.rb reference a variable that you manually export with heroku.